# Django allauth social login: automatically linking social site profiles using the registered email

Tags: django, django-1.5, django-allauth

I aim to create the **easiest login experience** possible for the users of my Django site. I imagine something like:

1. Login screen is presented to user
2. User selects to login with Facebook or Google
3. User enter password in external site
4. User can interact with my site as an authenticated user

Ok, this part is easy, just have to install [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) and configure it.

But I also want to give the option to use the site with a local user. It would have another step:

1. Login screen is presented to user
2. User selects to register
3. User enter credentials
4. Site sends a verification email
5. User clicks in email link and can interact with my site as an authenticated user

Ok, both the default authentication and allauth can do it. But now is the million dollars question.

**If they change how they do the login, how do I *automatically* associate their Google, FB and local accounts?**

See that any way they login, I have their email address. Is it possible to do it using django-allauth? I know I can do it with [user intervention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140021/django-allauth-linking-multiple-social-accounts-to-a-single-user/19353632#19353632). Today the default behavior is to refuse the login saying that the email is already registered.

If it isn't possible to do just with configuration, I'll accept the answer that gives me some orientation about which modifications should I make in allauth code to support this workflow.

There are a lot of reasons to do this. The users will forget which method they used to authenticate, and will sometimes use Google, sometimes FB and sometimes the local user account. We already have a lot of local user accounts and social accounts will be a new feature. I want the users to maintain their identity. I envision the possibility to ask for the user friends list, so if they logged using Google, I'd like to also have their FB account.

It is a hobby site, there isn't great security requirements, so please don't answer that this isn't a wise security implementation.

Later, I'd create a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) to have just the email as the login id. But I'll be happy with an answer that just let me automatically associate a accounts of the default user model that has a required username.

I'm using Django==1.5.4 and django-allauth==0.13.0

Comment: django-social-auth got just the thing you are looking for. you can put your authorization logic anywhere in social-auth pipeline in your settings. i don't know anything about all-auth but social-auth isn't hard to install and start working with, yet it has a lot of backends and very flexible

Comment: @PukeCloud: I didn't manage to get django-social-auth working. They are moving their project to another package called python-social-auth and the documentation is really confusing. I've got allauth working almost right out of the box. Reading around the web, other people also related that allauth is easier to work with. It looks like that allauth is gaining momentum. I'll wait a little more to see if someone answers here.

Comment: Allauth supports linking multiple social accounts to one user, so you can do all of the above using just allauth.

Comment: @elssar: sure, I know it support it. It has a really nice model to support it. I want to know how to do it automatically.

Comment: Automatically as in you get the users email and then from that email you automatically connect to their social accounts without user intervention?

Comment: Ah, that is what you want. Humm, I'm not sure if that is possible, or even something one should do.

Comment: @elssar: not so automatically:-) When the user authorized the login from the social site, their email is returned. If this email is already registered, I want it to be automatically associated to the existing account. Now If it happens, I get an "email already registered error".

Comment: Ah, now I get it. If an already registered user tries to use some other social login with the same email as she registered with, you want to log them into the already existing account. Okay, I'm pretty sure this is possible. Will have a look at allauth's code and get back to you.

Comment: I'll just leave it here for reference: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/418

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You will need to override the sociallogin adapter, specifically, the [`pre_social_login`](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/0.13.0/allauth/socialaccount/adapter.py#L18) method, which is called after authentication with the social provider, but before this login is processed by allauth.

In `my_adapter.py`, do something like this

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from allauth.account.models import EmailAccount
from allauth.exceptions import ImmediateHttpResponse
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter


class MyAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):
        # This isn't tested, but should work
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=sociallogin.email)
            sociallogin.connect(request, user)
            # Create a response object
            raise ImmediateHttpResponse(response)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            pass
```

And in your settings, change the social adapter to your adapter

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'myapp.my_adapter.MyAdapter`
```

And you should be able to connect multiple social accounts to one user this way.

Comment: works like a sharm! thanks! but right way for getting user for me is: `user = User.objects.get(email=sociallogin.account.user.email)`

Comment: actually didn't get this working. except some import error on `import EmailAccount`, and the comment above, it fails on 
`assert not self.is_existing`
https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/models.py#L219

Btw,the aacount is being connected. Can you provide full working example plz? Thank you.

Comment: the assert error will get thrown if you try to connect a socialaccount which is already saved. So just add a if condition check before to see if socialaccount has a pk. if it has return

Comment: Where is `response` in `raise ImmediateHttpResponse(response)` supposed to come from?

Comment: @nhinkle you have to create the response object yourself, like it says in the comment.

Comment: @elssar it seems like (from looking through the other solution below) just `return` is more effective than trying to use `raise ImmediateHttpResponse`.

Comment: @nhinkle I haven't worked with allauth for over a year and a half, so not quiet sure what happens after `pre_social_login` is called, but if all you want to do is to connect this social login with a pre-existing account, then I don't think you need to go further ahead in the registration flow. Just connect the accounts and login the user, then throw `ImmediateHttpResponse`to break out of the registration flow.

Answer (score 46):

**Note (2018-10-23)**: I'm not using this anymore. Too much magic happening. Instead I enabled `SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED` and `'facebook': { 'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False, ... }`. So allauth will redirect social logins on a social signup form to enter a valid email address. If it's already registered an error shows up to login first and then connect the account. Fair enough for me atm.

---

I'm trying to improve this kind of use case and came up with the following solution:

```
from allauth.account.models import EmailAddress
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter

class SocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):
        """
        Invoked just after a user successfully authenticates via a
        social provider, but before the login is actually processed
        (and before the pre_social_login signal is emitted).

        We're trying to solve different use cases:
        - social account already exists, just go on
        - social account has no email or email is unknown, just go on
        - social account's email exists, link social account to existing user
        """

        # Ignore existing social accounts, just do this stuff for new ones
        if sociallogin.is_existing:
            return

        # some social logins don't have an email address, e.g. facebook accounts
        # with mobile numbers only, but allauth takes care of this case so just
        # ignore it
        if 'email' not in sociallogin.account.extra_data:
            return

        # check if given email address already exists.
        # Note: __iexact is used to ignore cases
        try:
            email = sociallogin.account.extra_data['email'].lower()
            email_address = EmailAddress.objects.get(email__iexact=email)

        # if it does not, let allauth take care of this new social account
        except EmailAddress.DoesNotExist:
            return

        # if it does, connect this new social login to the existing user
        user = email_address.user
        sociallogin.connect(request, user)
```

As far as I can test it, it seems to work well. But inputs and suggestions are very welcome!

Comment: This works much better than the accepted answer. I'm using this and possibly integrating some modifications; I'll leave another comment if I come up with any good improvements.

Comment: This does work better than the expected answer, however I think you've assumed that the email address is verified, is that okay to assume?

Comment: Actually not, see Victor Grau Serrat answer. For example Facebook is not clear if every e-mail address is verified.

Comment: I based my solution on the above, but what worked for me, where you have return after the line except EmailAddress.DoesNotExist: I created the email address it was missing instead and then it worked ok.

Comment: Thank you all! It works fine! I tested with Google API.

Answer (score 14):

As per **babus** comment on [this related thread](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/215), the proposed answers posted before this one ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19443127/247696), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30591838/247696)) introduce a big security hole, documented in allauth docs:

> "It is not clear from the Facebook documentation whether or not the fact that the account is verified implies that the e-mail address is verified as well. For example, verification could also be done by phone or credit card. To be on the safe side, the default is to treat e-mail addresses from Facebook as unverified."
>
> Saying so, I can signup in facebook with your email ID or change my email to yours in facebook and login to the website to get access to your account.

So taking this into consideration, and building on @sspross answer, my approach is to redirect the user to the login page, and notify her/him of the duplicate, and inviting him to log in with her/his other account, and link them once they are logged in. I acknowledge that differs from the original question, but in doing so, no security hole is introduced.

Thus, my adapter looks like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from allauth.account.models import EmailAddress
from allauth.exceptions import ImmediateHttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter

class MyAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):
        """
        Invoked just after a user successfully authenticates via a
        social provider, but before the login is actually processed
        (and before the pre_social_login signal is emitted).

        We're trying to solve different use cases:
        - social account already exists, just go on
        - social account has no email or email is unknown, just go on
        - social account's email exists, link social account to existing user
        """

        # Ignore existing social accounts, just do this stuff for new ones
        if sociallogin.is_existing:
            return

        # some social logins don't have an email address, e.g. facebook accounts
        # with mobile numbers only, but allauth takes care of this case so just
        # ignore it
        if 'email' not in sociallogin.account.extra_data:
            return

        # check if given email address already exists.
        # Note: __iexact is used to ignore cases
        try:
            email = sociallogin.account.extra_data['email'].lower()
            email_address = EmailAddress.objects.get(email__iexact=email)

        # if it does not, let allauth take care of this new social account
        except EmailAddress.DoesNotExist:
            return

        # if it does, bounce back to the login page
        account = User.objects.get(email=email).socialaccount_set.first()
        messages.error(request, "A "+account.provider.capitalize()+" account already exists associated to "+email_address.email+". Log in with that instead, and connect your "+sociallogin.account.provider.capitalize()+" account through your profile page to link them together.")       
        raise ImmediateHttpResponse(redirect('/accounts/login'))
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280535/is-it-possible-to-check-if-an-email-is-confirmed-on-facebook

Comment: If you really want to "link social account to existing user" you have to replace "if it does, bounce back to the login page" part with just `sociallogin.connect(request, email_address.user)`

Comment: I have read that if FB does return an email it is guaranteed to be verified, so there really isn't a security issue anymore.

Comment: @EvanZamir Yes I read also that FB is now guaranteed to only return verified emails.

Answer (score 4):

I've just found this comment in the source code:

```
        if account_settings.UNIQUE_EMAIL:
            if email_address_exists(email):
                # Oops, another user already has this address.  We
                # cannot simply connect this social account to the
                # existing user. Reason is that the email adress may
                # not be verified, meaning, the user may be a hacker
                # that has added your email address to his account in
                # the hope that you fall in his trap.  We cannot check
                # on 'email_address.verified' either, because
                # 'email_address' is not guaranteed to be verified.
```

so, it is impossible to do by design.

Comment: is there any hook or trick by which this can be circumvented? I m stuck here :/

Answer (score 1):

> If they change how they do the login, how do I automatically associate their Google, FB and local accounts?

It is possible, but you have to be careful about security issues. Check scenario:

1. User create account via email and password on your site. User does not have Facebook.
2. Attacker creates account on Facebook with user email. (Hypothetic scenario, but you do not control if social network verify email).
3. Attacker login to your site with Facebook and automatically get access to user original account.

But you can fix it. I describe solution to ticket https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/1149

Happy scenario should be:

1. User create account via email and password on your site. User logged out.
2. User forget about his account and try to login via his Facebook.
3. System authenticate user via Facebook and find out, he already created account via other method (emails are same). System redirect user to normal login page with message "You already create your account using the email and password. Please log in this way. After you log in, you will be able to use and login using Facebook."
4. User login via email and password.
5. System automatically connect his Facebook login with his account. Next time user can use Facebook login or email and password.

Comment: But Facebook would request email verification, isn't it?