# django-rest-auth - Facebook social login raises unique constraint violation for existing email

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, facebook-login, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I implemented registration and login with django-allauth and django-rest-auth. I can successfully login with Facebook to the server with both allauth and rest-auth (web and mobile).

When I'm trying to login with FB account that its email already exists (someone already signed up with that email), it shows the signup form. However, when I'm trying doing the same using rest-auth, I get an error:

```
Internal Server Error: /rest-auth/facebook/

IntegrityError at /rest-auth/facebook/
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_user_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=() already exists.
```

My Configuration:

```
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'optional'
SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = False
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
```

Comment: email already exists where? can you please clear it.

Comment: @UmarAsghar I meant that someone already signed up with that email (not using facebook login)

Comment: If someone has already signed up with that email, then it does make sense to use the same email again for login. Can I know your case why you feel its needed?

Comment: By the way, I have tested that case, first I registered from the website as a regular user. Then later I did login with social app, then it just log me in with my previous account without giving any error. so I need to know your case and flow.

Comment: There is a bug in rest-auth. I found a solution here https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/pull/382

Comment: In addition, linking a social account to an existing account with the same email address can create a security hole, unless the email address is verified in both accounts.

Comment: You might be using outdated version. That can be the reason of it.

Comment: Why are you using allauth and rest-auth?

Comment: Yes, @EvanZamir

Comment: I upgrade to v.0.9.3 and now am getting an error "User is already registered with this e-mail address" when I try to do FB login after having already signed up for an email account. How to fix this? I opened up a github issue on the project but nobody has answered yet. https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/409

Comment: @UmarAsghar It does make sense to use FB Login, because you might have signed up a long time ago and not remember username or password you gave, and it's just easier to use the FB login. I do it all the time. In fact I do it on SO very often.

Comment: @EvanZamir I used it recently and i also do it very often.

Comment: @EvanZamir What would you like to do in that case? You can merge the accounts or ask for another email address?

Comment: I would merge the accounts. That is the whole point of having a FB login button. It’s for convenience. Asking a user to create an entirely new account with the same email makes no sense. Nor does asking for a new email. Have you ever seen an app with hat behavior? I sure haven’t.

Comment: @EvanZamir I'll post my code here to do that. Please note that if you decide to do that, then you should verify the user email address. Otherwise, you might create a security problem (another user can sign up with your email and get an access it once you connect your FB account)

Comment: Hmm that’s true. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I solved the issue by creating a social adapter that connects the existing account to the social account.
Please make sure you're aware of the risks before using it - if the email address is not verified in one of the accounts a malicious user might take control of the account by signing up before the social signup (for example).

```
class MySocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):

        user = sociallogin.user
        if user.id:
            return
        if not user.email:
            return

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=user.email)  # if user exists, connect the account to the existing account and login
            sociallogin.connect(request, user)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception('Social adapter failure - {}'.format(e))
```

You need to set the path to the adapter in the settings.py:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'path.to.MySocialAccountAdapter'
```

Comment: I'm trying this out now, and when I do a simple `print(sociallogin.user)` it appears to be empty. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm just getting `django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: SocialAccount has no user.`

Comment: This answer solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30591838/1245418

Comment: What was the problem? It'd be better if we fix the answer above (if needed)

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of [django-rest-auth](https://github.com/tivix/django-rest-auth/) [v0.9.3](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/releases/tag/v0.9.3) now includes social connect views, which allow you to link existing account to a social account.

In order to use them you need to be authenticated via existing account, due to security issues outlined in the previous answer. More info in the docs: [Additional Social Connect Views](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#additional-social-connect-views)

Unique constraint 500 error is fixed as well.