# Django : Getting Facebook Friend List for user Already Logged in

Tags: django, facebook-graph-api, django-allauth

[ Using django all-auth ]
Use-Case :

1) User can login with [email,password] or facebook 
2) User is Currently logged in by [email,password]
3) How to obtain fb friend list in this case ??

Options :

1) Logout user and redirect to login with FB page .

Is there any other gracefully way to do this . 
using some other django social-auth app can help in my use-case ??

Comment: got my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504883/django-allauth-multiple-social-accounts-with-a-custom-user