# logout and login with different twitter account using ( Django + Allauth )

Tags: python, django, twitter, django-allauth

I am using Allauth to login with twitter in my Django app. 
I have a problem to logout from existing account to login with different one.

I make logout in function logout in my views.py
and within it i tried to call:

```
from django.contrib import auth 
auth.logout(request)
```

but it didn't work.

I also tried to expire session using this:

```
request.session.set_expiry(1)
```

to expire the session after 1 second, but it also didn't work.

By the way I use my own signup and login (I just save mail and password)

So Any ideas?

Comment: Read `allauth` configuration documentation, https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html, especially this part `ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET` and `
`ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL`, you can configure this in your `settings.py`. You can use `allauth` [account](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/master/allauth/templates/account) templates to configure this. You don't need to specify it in the `views.py`

Comment: I tried to set logut url to be accounts/logout, it opens page to check sign out then redirect me to index. when i try to login again, it opens the existing account

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504883/django-allauth-multiple-social-accounts-with-a-custom-user

Comment: I tried all of them, but they make connection with existing account not new one. I think solution might be on closing the session.

Comment: you need to work with [social-account-tags](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates.html#social-account-tags) if you want to customize it for multiple accounts

Comment: I tried to use: connect,login and reauthenticate, and all of them do the same job >> login with existing account, none of them logged me out

Answer (score 0):

All auth takes care of it, jut build a url to:
/accounts/logout/

No need to write your own view. If you want to know what it does you could override their view.